# how to debug a page that wont open (blank page)

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

here is how i open tabs

```
    await page.goto( url , {timeout: 90000} )
        .catch(function(error){
            page.close();

        }
    );
```

i open multiple pages in 1 browser in a loop  , one particle page (which is the first tab i open) wont open the first time (first loop) and i get timeout error , it works in the next loop just fine  ... i tried to capture screen shot and its just a blank page  .... i have the same code working fine on

so my question is is there anyway to gather information about why the page wont open ?  is it late response or something else ?

Comment: A good way to debug issues like this is to run puppeteer non-headless, for ex.: `puppeteer.launch({headless: false})`

Comment: @ZsoltGyöngyösi thus happens on the server i cant run it headless:false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Puppeteer documentation includes [debugging tips](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer#debugging-tips), which list:

1. Turning off headless mode with `headless: false` to see what the browser is displaying:

   ```
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
     headless: false,
   });
   ```
2. Slowing down Puppeteer operations using the `slowMo` option to help see what's going on:

   ```
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
     headless: false,
     slowMo: 200, // slow down by 200ms
   });
   ```
3. Capturing console output:

   ```
   page.on('console', msg => {
     console.log('Page Log from Evaluate:', msg.text());
   });

   await page.evaluate(() => {
     console.log('Current URL:', location.href);
   });
   ```
4. Stopping test execution and using a debugger in the browser:

   - Using `devtools: true` when launching Puppeteer:

     ```
     const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
       devtools: true,
     });
     ```
   - Changing default test timeout:

     ```
     jest.setTimeout(100000);                   // Jest
     jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 100000; // Jasmine
     this.timeout(100000);                      // Mocha
     ```
   - Adding an evaluate statement with `debugger` inside, or adding `debugger` to an existing evaluate statement:

     ```
     await page.evaluate(() => {
       debugger;
     });
     ```
5. Enabling verbose logging:

   ```
   # Basic verbose logging
   env DEBUG="puppeteer:*" node script.js

   # Debug output can be enabled/disabled by namespace
   env DEBUG="puppeteer:protocol" node script.js # protocol connection messages
   env DEBUG="puppeteer:session" node script.js # protocol session messages (protocol messages to targets)

   # Protocol traffic can be rather noisy. This example filters out all Network domain messages
   env DEBUG="puppeteer:session" env DEBUG_COLORS=true node script.js 2>&1 | grep -v '"Network'
   ```
6. Debugging Puppeteer (Node.js) code, using [ndb](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb) or [npx](https://github.com/zkat/npx):

   - `npm install -g ndb`
   - Adding a `debugger` to your Puppeteer (Node.js) code
   - `ndb jest` or `ndb mocha` (or `npx ndb jest` / `npx ndb mocha`)

---

You may want to also look into the Puppeteer documentation regarding [error handling](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#error-handling):

> For certain types of errors Puppeteer uses specific error classes. These classes are available via `require('puppeteer/Errors')`.

List of supported classes:

- [`TimeoutError`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-timeouterror)

Example Usage:

```
const { TimeoutError } = require('puppeteer/Errors');

// ...

try {
  await page.waitForSelector('.foo');
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof TimeoutError) {
    // Handle TimeoutError here ...
  }
}
```

Comment: i wanted to leave a comment and thank you for such a complete answer but apparently its against the SO guideline so i wont ;)